# How to configure OAM as Service Provider for SAML SSO

Tags: saml-2.0, oracle-access-manager

We are on Oracle Access Manager 12c (12.2.1.3).

I have been doing SAML Federation where OAM acts as IdP and it's all working good. But, now we have a requirement to make OAM as Service Provider (SP) and IdP will be Okta on the other side.

What is the process to achieve this. Any document or link which outlines the steps would be grateful.

Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since I no longer have an account at Oracle to vet this, I'm posting it as a comment rather than an answer... But, as a customer running their software, I presume you have access to the docs: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2322401_1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [Oracle document that describes how to set up OAM as Service Provider](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2322401_1.html). This document is valid for your version of Oracle Access Manager 12c And on Okta side [read these steps to Create an Identity Provider in Okta](https://docs.helpscout.com/article/878-okta-identity-provider).
The purpose of these two separate steps is to establish a Federation between the two end points, the Service Provider (SP) and the Identity Provider (IDP). So you set up configuration on Oracle Access Manager and then on the Okta. Here as per your use case SP is OAM and IDP is Okta. There will be a step where you will exchange saml metadata between the two entities- your SP and IDP. Once saml metadata has been exchanged between the two end points, both entities will be in a Federation with Okta acting as the Identity Provider and OAM as the Service Provider. In summary you will create users on the Okta side and application will be protected by OAM. When user tries to access the application, since federation is in place, the user will be redirected automatically to the Okta Identity Provider where user will authenticate, upon authentication, the saml token will be passed on (via browser redirects) to the OAM, and if authentication is successful and saml token is valid, OAM will allow access to the protected application.